# How to get the date 28 days after a given date?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, date

I have a date of format `YYYY-MM-DD`, and I want to display the 28th day from the given day. I tried some ways but couldn't fix it. If possible, I'd like a solution without using Moment.js

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29024/)

If there is no other solution, can someone help me use Moment.js?

Comment: You should look into [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/). Working with dates is gnarly due to leap years, month lengths, etc. Their library makes it simple.

Comment: @Turnip  that is different

Comment: Yes..I am asking ,that I had one date in format YYYY-MM-DD .now how can we get the 28th day from the given day in same format

Answer (score 6):

Here's a function that I turned into a Date prototype that handles date offsets:

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days)
{
    var day = new Date(this.valueOf());
    day.setDate(day.getDate() + days);
    return day;
}


d = new Date
d.addDays(28)
```

Comment: Does addDays() exists on the date object ?https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: `addDays` is not a standard method on the date object in any javascript implementation. So no one will have this method.

Comment: @rckrd I have edited my post. I must have had that function saved into my Date prototype from earlier.

Answer (score 6):

```
    var date =new Date("2016-08-30");    
    var newDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate()+28)
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29024/

Comment: can u check this year does looks correct

Comment: sorry given u the wrong js fiddle

Comment: correct one https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29025/

Comment: Can someone look above,year doesnt looks correct

Comment: Replace `getYear()` with `getFullYear()`

Comment: @AlexK Thanks man it worked

Comment: Using the Date constructor (or Date.parse) to parse an ISO 8601 format date may result in a date that appears to be the previous day for users in a timezone west of Greenwich.

Comment: I made those changes to the above.

Answer (score 2):

So you basically want to add 28 days to the given date? Then this is for you.

```
var d = new Date(2016, 7, 30)  // parsing dates is a different task
// d equals Tue Aug 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
var offset = 28 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var newDate = new Date(d.getTime() + offset)
// newDate equals Tue Sep 27 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

In case you also want to parse / stringify the date you could use:

```
// parse date
var dateStr = '2016-08-30';
var date = new Date(dateStr);

// stringify date
date.toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

java script :

```
var today = new Date();
var noDaysToAdd = 28;
someDate.setDate(today() + noDaysToAdd); 
Formatting to YYYY-MM-DD :
var dd = someDate.getDate();
var mm = someDate.getMonth() + 1;
var y = someDate.getFullYear();

var someFormattedDate = y + '-' + mm + '-' + dd ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
 var d=new Date("2016-08-30");
 var n=28; //number of days to add. 
 $scope.renewaldate=new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()+n);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/NaghaveerGowda/4gk0L6zx/1/)

Initializing the date variable

For **UTC time**

Using `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))` you can create a Date-object from a specific UTC time.

**Non-UTC**

Get timezone using `getTimezoneOffset()` and then set the time

```
var d = new Date(xiYear, xiMonth, xiDate);
d.setTime( d.getTime() + d.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000 );
```

Comment: Using the Date constructor (or Date.parse) to parse an ISO 8601 format date may result in a date that appears to be the previous day for users in a timezone west of Greenwich.

Comment: @RobG Yes, I agree. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest converting your date to a timestamp, adding `100 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 28` (the number of milliseconds in 28 days) to it, and converting it back to a human-readable date.

```
var now = new Date(
  (new Date()).valueOf()
  + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 28
)
```

and then you will need to format it as

```
console.log(now.getFullYear()
            + "-"
            + (now.getMonth() + 1) 
            + "-"
            + (now.getDays() + 1)
)
```

The `+ 1` is because JavaScript gives days and months as between `0` to `11` rather than `1` to `12`.

There is still the problem that you are getting `5` instead of `05` so you might need to write yourself a function like

```
function forceTwoDigits(val){
    val = String(val) // Force value to be a string.
    if(val.length == 1) return "0" + val;
    return val; // If it hasn't returned yet
}
```